# O_PATH equivalent in MacOS?

Tags: c, macos, posix

Linux has the `O_PATH` flag to open() which allows one to get a fd to be used in fstat, fcntl and others without actually opening the file for reading (or having permissions to do so). However the `O_PATH` flag is Linux specific.

Is there an equivalent to the `O_PATH` flag to open() in MacOS? For example, how can I use fstat() on a file I don't have read permissions for?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the actual problem that you think using this will solve? Or is it just plain curiosity (which is fine, but please [edit] your question to say so)?

Comment: The problem is being able to call fstat() and later flistxattr() knowing I'm operating on the same inode (and not having TOCTOU) on files I don't have read permissions for (or are problematic when opening for reading, like some special files in /dev).
The normal pattern would be to call fd = open(...) and then fstat(fd, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS doesn't have an equivalent to `O_PATH`, so it's impossible to have a reference to a file without opening it. Regarding the one bit of functionality that you mentioned, you can call `stat` with a given file path as long as you have "execution" rights to its parent directory, regardless of whether you have any rights to that file.

Comment: Anyway to gurantee that if I call listxattr() later it will be on the same file?

Comment: Not that I know of. Despite a multi-user foundation, Darwin favors single (human) users and heavy isolation, so it's unusual to want to stat a file for which you don't have read access. Most files would either be plainly inaccessible, like some system-controlled databases, or at least accessible for reading; there isn't much of an in-between. I don't have a lot of context into what you're doing, but I'd suggest going for fstat on macOS and telling users that they need read access to files that they want to stat, even if that's not entirely true.